# Does overloading operator '<<' require and initialization?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading, ostream

I am receiving the error "declaration of reference variable 'operator' requires an initialization" in my main.cpp.
In the constructor have already tried including:

```
friend ostream& operater << (ostream& out, Coins& c)
```

in the header file, however the error still occurs. Also, I tried adding

```
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>
```

in the header file.

This is the function I am using.

```
myfile.h
    ostream& operater << (ostream& out, Coins& c){
        c.print(out);
        return out;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please read the [help] overview for creating a [mcve], and edit your question accordingly. Your question fails to meet all the requirements for a [mcve] as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help].

Comment: Typo. `operater` -> `operator`.

Comment: Voting to close for typo.